# What is the significance of, and reason for, wrapping the entire content of a JavaScript source file in a function block?

Tags: javascript, function

What is the significance of, wrapping the entire content of a JavaScript source file in a function block?

Answer (score 3):

It is common practice to wrap browser JavaScript in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) in order to keep variables private and not pollute the [global scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

Global variables are [generally considered bad](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478). They encourage error-prone patterns and make it more difficult to reason about your programs.

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) has a nifty trick up its sleeve where it actually [wraps your module](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/) in a function automagically on your behalf. As a result, you will almost never see anyone wrap their Node.js code in an IIFE. Though you may still see it used inline to scope a small chunk of code.

Thanks to [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) and block scoping we can actually avoid the slight overhead of an IIFE by using a block statement instead.

```
{
    const foo = 1;
    // ... code that you would put in an IIFE ...
    // ... but do NOT use `var` ...
}
console.log(foo);  // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

**Further reading:**
https://www.sitepoint.com/joys-block-scoping-es6/

Comment: thanx @seth holladay

Comment: No problem @dpk45. And welcome to Stack Overflow. :) I am happy to provide more details if you need. Otherwise, feel free to accept the answer.